# Comparing JPEG images in PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, jpeg, image-comparison

I am trying to assert equality between JPEG Images using PIL:
Currently, I'm relying on exact comparison using the following:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageChops
img1 = Image.open("tmp_img.jpg")
img2 = Image.open("tmp_img.jpg")
ImageChops.difference(img1, img2).getbbox() is None
```

This works fine and outputs `True` for the above example.

The problem is, after saving and loading the image:

```
img1.save("tmp_img_2.jpg")
img3 = Image.open("tmp_img_2.jpg")
ImageChops.difference(img1, img3).getbbox() is None
```

It outputs `False` and I suppose the reason is JPEG compression.

My question is, what metric should I use, in order to assert equality as reliably as possible?
I could use MSE as described [here](https://pyimagesearch.com/2014/09/15/python-compare-two-images/). As a threshold I would save and load the image 10 times and see how big the MSE gets after 10 compressions.

But this depends on the specific image I'm using and also feels kind of dumb.

Is there a more generic way to check whether two JPEGs are equal regardless of (repeated) compression?

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand. If you want images to be identical, use a lossless format. If you don't need them to be identical, use lossy and accept there'll be losses.

Comment: I'm writing an integration test where a service sends an image to another. And it uses JPEG so i can't change the format. I need to test whether the "correct" image arrives or not. That is, I need to test if the service has somehow butchered the image (messed up size or rotation, lost color information etc.). I don't necessarily "want" them to be identical. I need to test whether they are or not.